# How to specify the sequence of tests?

Tags: android, testing, automated-tests, android-espresso

I have 3 tests, but they do not run in the order in which they are written. The first one is always checkMoneyBackButton(), although it is written last. How can I specify the order of execution?

```
 @Test
 public void checkContentAuthorizationWindow() throws Exception {

    //test1 body...

 }


@Test
public void checkContentCardsWindow() throws Exception {

    //test2 body...

 }

@Test
public void checkMoneyBackButton() throws Exception {

    //test3 body...

 }
```

Comment: Why does it matter?

Comment: Also, we do not add `throws Exception` on unit tests

Comment: There will be a lot of tests and toga. Therefore, I find it more convenient for testing